# Make: Match date in file name write in file and write file to new location

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to use a makefile to take files like (of course all of this will need to be generalized):

```
src/post/2015-01-01-filename.md
```

and write to

```
content/post/filename.md
```

with the part of the file name `2015-01-01` to the file. So the unix part would be something like:

```
sed '1 adate: 2015-01-01' > content/post/filename.md
```

in the makefile I would write something like:

```
content/%.md: $(subst ./,,$(shell find ./src/post/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-.*\.md'))
```

I'm not quite sure on how to strip out the date and get it to paste into file and match it with the makefile.

Is there a simple straight forward solution to this?

Also, if the original file is named like `2015-01-01.filename.md` make it easier to do all this?

**Update**

This is what I have so far, still not working quite yet though:

```
POST_SRC := $(subst ./,,$(shell find ./src/post/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-.*\.md'))

define POSTS_PARSE
_target := $(shell $1 | grep -Po '\w+\.md')
POSTS := $$(POSTS) $$(_target)
$$(_target): $1
    date=$(basename $< | grep -Po '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}');\
        cat $< | sed '1 a'$date > $@
endef

$(foreach x,$(POST_SRC),$(eval $(call POSTS_PARSE,$x)))

posts: $(POSTS)
```

Comment: Do you know the date?  Can you not make it a `make` variable and simply set it appropriately, using it to build the file names?  Or do you have to find what files are there and adjust to the date that you find?

Comment: The latter. The original information was for illustration/simplification purposes only.

Comment: Then I don't think I'd be using `make` for this task; it really isn't designed for it.  I'd have a general purpose shell script to do the job, and maybe invoked the shell script from a `makefile` if that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Not sure if there is a better way.

```
POST_SRC := $(subst ./,,$(shell find ./src/post/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-.*\.md'))

define POSTS_PARSE
_target := $(shell echo $1 | grep -Po '\w+\.md')
POSTS := $$(POSTS) $$(_target)
$$(_target): $1
  date=$$$$(basename $$< | grep -Po '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'); \
    sed "1 adate: $$$$date" $$< > $$@
endef

$(foreach x,$(POST_SRC),$(eval $(call POSTS_PARSE,$x)))

posts: $(POSTS)
```